# How to add extensions to AiLiveComplete?

Tags: android, extension-methods, android-notifications, app-inventor

I'm developing an app using AiLiveComplete! for testing purposes, and I'd like to add some useful extensions as [this](https://puravidaapps.com/notification.php) one.

Can this be done with the offline App Inventor 2 version? In case it is not possible to add extensions in this version, is there another way to have the app notify user for a search result in the notification bar?

Please advise. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The App Inventor Extension feature is currently in testing, [see also the announcement here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/Ip2AX036d0U/5NJlAEbFCgAJ). Currently you only can use extensions on [the test server](http://extension-test.appinventor.mit.edu/).

You will have to wait, until the extension feature is released in production and a new version of AiLiveComplete is published.

Btw. the best place to ask questions about AiLiveComplete is in the [AiLiveComplete forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/apptomarket)...

> Can this be done with the offline App Inventor 2 version?

no

> is there another way to have the app notify user for a search result
> in the notification bar?

I don't think so

Comment: Taifun, thank you for your respond. By the way do you think is possible to have the user notified by an SMS send to oneself number using the blocks as in AlertMe tutorial? Is this a possibility or I'm missing smthing here?

Comment: the [Google Voice feature of the texting component](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/social.html#Texting) only works in the United States. I'm not located in the United States, so I don't know, if this will work... you might want to try something yourself...

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)